# How to create a File Folder (C# Programming)

Tags: c#

How to create a windows folder in windows(except right click new folder). like

I want to create a folder through C# code in any drive(D, E etc..).

Thanks in advance...

Comment: What have you done so far? Can you post the code?

Comment: Read MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/54a0at6s(v=vs.110).aspx

You can use command line, VBA script and other ways to create directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Directory` class provided in `System.IO` namespace.

This class exposes static methods for creating, moving, and enumerating through directories and subdirectories.

For creating a directory named **Test** on D drive you can use following in the code:

```
 System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(@"D:\\Test");
```

MSDN Reference: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: `try this` is not an explained answer

Comment: Right @RUJordan. I have added more explanation. Thank you.